# test-first- ruby 00_hello parse error: OptionParser::InvalidOption

Tags: ruby, parsing, rspec

I am having a hard time figure out the first lesson on Test-First Ruby (Alex Chaffee), I am running "rake" test and am getting errors that I am not supposed to receive.

I already tried doing the `gem update --system` and removing spaces as suggested in previous posts. None of this solved the problem.

Bellow are my specs and errors received.

I will appreciate any help.

```
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\Greice>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (4.1.4)
activerecord (4.1.4)
activesupport (4.1.4)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.1.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.6.5)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
feedtools (0.2.29)
hpricot (0.8.6)
i18n (0.6.11)
io-console (0.4.2, 0.3)
json (1.8.1, 1.5.5)
minitest (5.4.0, 2.5.1)
rake (10.3.2, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (4.1.1, 3.9.5)
RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32)
rspec (3.0.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-core (3.0.3, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (3.0.3, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (3.0.3, 2.0.1)
rspec-support (3.0.3)
rubygems-update (2.4.1)
sunlight-congress (1.1.0)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tzinfo (1.2.1)
uuidtools (2.1.4)


C:\Users\Greice\Desktop\test-first-ruby-master>cd 00_hello

C:\Users\Greice\Desktop\test-first-ruby-master\00_hello>rake
(in C:/Users/Greice/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/option_parse
r.rb:18:in `parse!': invalid option: --warnings (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/option_parser.rb:4:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/configuration_options.rb:78:in `parse_options_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/configuration_options.rb:74:in `parse_global_options'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/configuration_options.rb:48:in `parse_options'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/runner.rb:41:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core
/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec -IC:/Users/Greice/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/00_he
llo -IC:/Users/Greice/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/00_hello/solution -f docume
ntation -r ./rspec_config "C:/Users/Greice/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/00_hel
lo/hello_spec.rb" failed

Tasks: TOP => default => spec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Rakefile**

```
# This Rakefile has all the right settings to run the tests inside each lab
gem 'rspec', '~>2'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

desc "run tests for this lab"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  lab = Rake.application.original_dir.gsub(' ', '\ ')
  task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
  task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f documentation', '-r ./rspec_config']
  task.verbose = false
end
```

**rspec_config.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.fail_fast = true
  c.color = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when `--warnings` was an option in the `.rspec` file.

Try removing the `--warnings` line from your `.rspec` or `rspec_config` file.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the rspec_config file and it doesn't contain any --warnings.

Comment: Could you add your `Rakefile` and your `rspec_config` file to the question? That might have some hints. :)